# PHP: How to ensure a sentence inputted into a form has at least 20 characters with the last 9 characters being pulled to display on a new page?

Tags: php

PHP: How to ensure a sentence inputted into a form has at least 20 characters with the last 9 characters being pulled to display on a new page?

```
<?php

//Sentence Code
if ($sentence > 20) {
    $newstring = subtr($sentence, -9);

} else {
    echo 'ERROR! Your sentence is too short. At least 20 characters are required.</br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: See [strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: Depending how you do it, wouldn't it be better to have a limit on the input field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen() for this.

```
<?php
 //Sentence Code
 if(!empty($sentence)){
      if (strlen($sentence) > 20) {
          $newstring = subtr($sentence, -9);
      } else {
         echo 'ERROR! Your sentence is too short. At least 20 characters are required.</br>';
      }
 }
?>
```